# How to get specific String within a string and turn into Array using PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-match

How can I get a specific string within a string using PHP?

i tried to used `preg_match`, but the result was not what I wanted.

Example String:

> Creator: Adobe InDesign CC (Macintosh) Producer: Adobe PDF Library 10.0.1 CreationDate: Fri Aug 8 10:37:26 2014 ModDate: Fri Aug 8 10:37:29 2014 Tagged: no Form: none Pages: 2 Encrypted: no Page size: 612.283 x 858.898 pts (rotated 0 degrees) MediaBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 CropBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 BleedBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 TrimBox: 8.50 8.50 603.78 850.39 ArtBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 File size: 28176860 bytes Optimized: no PDF version: 1.6

This is a result for pdfinfo test.pdf comandline:

What i want.. is to get the specific string like this:

> MediaBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 CropBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 BleedBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 TrimBox: 8.50 8.50 603.78 850.39 ArtBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90

And put it in an array list.. The result would be something like this:

```
[
'Mediabox'  => [0.00,0.00,612.28,858.90],
'CropBox'   => [0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90],
'BleedBox'  => [0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90],
'TrimBox'   => [8.50 8.50 603.78 850.39]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, explode the string at spaces

```
$str = "MediaBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 CropBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 BleedBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 TrimBox: 8.50 8.50 603.78 850.39 ArtBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90"; 
$array = array(); 

foreach (explode(" ",$str) as $value)
{
    if (!is_numeric($value))
        $box = substr($value, 0, -1);
    else
        $array[$box][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: This one is correct to. Much Simpler... thanks Lenny

Answer (score 2):

I tested this code and it seems to produce your expected output:

```
$str = "Creator: Adobe InDesign CC (Macintosh) Producer: Adobe PDF Library 10.0.1 CreationDate: Fri Aug 8 10:37:26 2014 ModDate: Fri Aug 8 10:37:29 2014 Tagged: no Form: none Pages: 2 Encrypted: no Page size: 612.283 x 858.898 pts (rotated 0 degrees) MediaBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 CropBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 BleedBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 TrimBox: 8.50 8.50 603.78 850.39 ArtBox: 0.00 0.00 612.28 858.90 File size: 28176860 bytes Optimized: no PDF version: 1.6";

$matches = array();
$count   = preg_match_all("/(MediaBox|CropBox|BleedBox|TrimBox):\s([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/", $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

header("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

array_shift($matches);

$str_keys   = $matches[0];
$str_values = $matches[1];
$result     = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
  $result[$str_keys[$i]] = explode(" ", $str_values[$i]);
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "MediaBox": [
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "612.28",
        "858.90"
    ],
    "CropBox": [
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "612.28",
        "858.90"
    ],
    "BleedBox": [
        "0.00",
        "0.00",
        "612.28",
        "858.90"
    ],
    "TrimBox": [
        "8.50",
        "8.50",
        "603.78",
        "850.39"
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following regex, you will get two capturing groups for each match. The first one is the key in your associative array, the second one is the value.

Here is the regex to use in `preg_match` for example:

```
(MediaBox|CropBox|BleedBox|TrimBox):((?: (?:\d+(?:\.\d{1,2}))){3})
```